# getJSON scope and variable definitions

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am having trouble understanding why my code is not running properly. Namely, I am confused as to why `foo.bar` is `undefined` after the function runs, but is defined within the function.

```
function async(foo, n) {

  console.log("getting value number: " + n);

  $.getJSON("database.json", function(data) {
    foo.bar = data.value[n];
    console.log(foo.bar); // this works
  });
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var foo = new String();

async(foo, 0);

console.log(foo.bar); // doesn't work
```

The [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)console outputs the following:

```
>getting stop number: 0
>undefined
>defined
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` will run the call back asynchronously. Which is to say it is non blocking and will only run the callback after it receives the response, which is after all the rest of you code has run.

Comment: is there a correct way to write my code? that is, to write it in a way where foo.bar is defined without running getJSON synchronously?

Comment: The correct thing to do is to process the response in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

```
function async(foo, n) {
        // «foo» is a parameter that only exists in the context of the function «async()», the same way for «n».

        console.log("getting value number: " + n);

        $.getJSON( "database.json", function(data) {
        // Dynamically, the Javascript engine foo is interpreted as an object, because your result is an object with a specific value.
            foo.bar = data.value[n];
        // You're overwriting foo parameter with the new result. (data.value[n]).

        // Then
            console.log(foo.bar);    // this works!
        });
}
```

And:

```
var foo = new String();
```

**foo** is a primitive object of String.

When you do:

```
console.log(foo);
```

You get this in the console:

```
String {length: 0, [[PrimitiveValue]]: ""}
```

In this line:

```
async(foo, 0);
```

You're calling the async function with the primitive object of String and «0» as parameters.

**Updated with a proper solution:**

> By default, the final value of a variable that depends of an
>   asynchronous or synchronous request, will be completed with the
>   desired value when the request is completed. This depends on the
>   response from the server.
>
> You need to wait for the response from the server to assign a variable
>   with the final value and then display it.

You should try this:

```
var foo = {}; // Declare an object.
foo.bar; // Add bar attribute in this object.


function async(n) {
    console.log("getting value number: " + n);

    $.getJSON("database.json", function (data) {
        foo.bar = data.value[n]; // foo.bar has a new value from the Asynchronous request.
        printResult(); // Call printResult function to print in the console.
    });
}

function printResult() {
    console.log(foo.bar);
}


// Execute async function.
async(0);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/jh67vu7n/)

Comment: do you have a suggestion as to how to "fix" this, or how to write it properly?

Comment: Yes, of course, I've just updated my answer with a solution.